# Manually Parsing a a JSON into an Object of a Struct

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner in swift and I'm currently making an app that makes a web request. I've been trying to parse this JSON Data but the nested data is just really hard to wrap my head around:

```
 "abilities": [
            {
                "ability": {
                    "name": "chlorophyll",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/34/"
                },
                "is_hidden": true,
                "slot": 3
            },
            {
                "ability": {
                    "name": "overgrow",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/65/"
                },
                "is_hidden": false,
                "slot": 1
            }
        ]
```

JSon Serialization Code

```
let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            guard let json = jsonAny as? [String: Any] else { return }
```

This is my attempt to manually parse the JSON Data

```
    private func parsePokemonManual(json: [String: Any]) -> Pokemon {
        let abilities = json["abilities"] as? [String: Any] ?? [String: Any]()

        return Pokemon(abilities: abilities)
    }
}
```

These are the structs that I made to hold the data.

```
struct Abilities {
    let ability : Ability

    struct Ability {
        let name : String
    }
}
```

How do I successfully parse the JSON Data into an object of Pokemon structure?

With this code so fat I am getting the error "Cannot convert the value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[Abilities]'. My problem is that I don't know what type to cast the abilities as and that my struct 'Abilities' is also incorrect.

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome to SO! Thanks for the detail level of detail in your question. Could you add some details to describe what actually is going wrong? Is the code failing when you try to parse the JSON, or when you try to access the objects inside the parsed object? Can you post an error message? These might help you get an answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems with your attempt although one might argue there is only 1, that you should use `Codable` instead but lets stay with JSONSerialization here. The problems are

- You are reading the json wrong and should cast not to a dictionary but an array of dictionaries when accessing "abilities"
- Your struct is to complicated, maybe because of the previous problem
- Lastly, you can't cast into a custom type, you need to convert or *map* the data into your type by telling exactly what values to use and how because the compiler doesn't understand how to do it.

First the struct can be simplified to

```
struct Ability {
    let name : String
}
```

And the rest is fixed in the function `parsePokemonManual`. First get "abilities" and cast to an array of dictionaries. Then map each item in the array by getting "ability" and casting it to a dictionary that is used to get the "name" value that is then used when creating an instance of `Ability`

```
private func parsePokemonManual(json: [String: Any]) -> [Ability] {
    guard let abilities = json["abilities"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return []
    }

    return abilities.compactMap { dict in
        guard let ability = dict["ability"] as? [String: String], let name = ability["name"] else { return nil }

        return Ability(name: name)
    }
}
```